# Passive voice that is not the main voice in a language

Tags: passive, austronesian

I have a sentence as an example:

Patient Trigger

> Gipalit nako ang mangga.

Agent Trigger

> Nipalit ko ug mangga.

I don't understand the contrast.

IMO Patient trigger is default and is used for talking about an actual event than agent trigger which talks about as if it is narrated.

Now why does they tell these languages uses passive voice as the main voice?

Comment: Which language is that? Many Austronesian languages have a voice system that isn't best labelled as "active/passive".

Comment: It is Bisaya/Cebuano. It is the largest language in the Philippines.